# Check access for website addresses in Laravel

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

Sorry because my English is weak and I can not speak well!!

This is the route I defined on the web.php page :

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\GoogleAuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UrlController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('project.index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth' , 'InfoFolder' , 'verified' , 'Roles'] , 'prefix' => 'users/'] , function(){
    
    Route::get('{url}', [UrlController::class , 'urlpanel'])->name('users_url');


});
```

And my controller code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


class UrlController extends Controller
{

    //

    public function urlpanel($url){

        $admin = "admin";
        $pages = "admin.pages";
        $charts = "admin.pages.charts";
        $examples = "admin.pages.examples";
        $forms = "admin.pages.forms";
        $mailbox = "admin.pages.mailbox";
        $tables = "admin.pages.tables";
        $UI = "admin.pages.UI";





        $link_panel = [

            'index' => "$admin.index",
            'index2' => "$admin.index2",
            'index3' => "$admin.index3",
            'calendar' => "$pages.calendar",
            'widgets' => "$pages.widgets",
            'chartjs' => "$charts.chartjs",
            'flot' => "$charts.flot",
            'inline' => "$charts.inline",
            '404' => "$examples.404",
            '500' => "$examples.500",
            'blank' => "$examples.blank",
            'invoice-print' => "$examples.invoice-print",
            'invoice' => "$examples.invoice",
            'lockscreen' => "$examples.lockscreen",
            'login' => "$examples.login",
            'profile' => "$examples.profile",
            'register' => "$examples.register",
            'advanced' => "$forms.advanced",
            'editors' => "$forms.editors",
            'general' => "$forms.general",
            'compose' => "$mailbox.compose",
            'mailbox' => "$mailbox.mailbox",
            'read-mail' => "$mailbox.read-mail",
            'data' => "$tables.data",
            'simple' => "$tables.simple",
            'buttons' => "$UI.buttons",
            'general' => "$UI.general",
            'icons' => "$UI.icons",
            'sliders' => "$UI.sliders",



        ];

        $link_permission_owner = [
            'index2',
        ];




        if(!isset($link_panel[$url])){
            return abort(404);
        }
        if(in_array($link_panel[$url] , $link_panel)){
            
            if(in_array($url , $link_permission_owner) && Auth::user()->hasRole(['member']))
            {
                return abort(404);
            }
            try {
                $active = "active";
                return view($link_panel[$url] , compact('active'));
            }
            catch (\Exception $e)
            {
                return abort(404);
            }

            try {
                    $active = "active";
                    return view($link_panel[$url] , compact('active'));
                }
                catch (\Exception $e)
                {
                    return abort(404);
                }
        }
    }




}
```

This is the code I wrote for users to access the files

But it is very dirty

Is there no better way to reach users?

I want some of the pages I have specified in the presentation to be viewed only by admins

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you explain why you are using 1 `Controller` and 1 `Route`. It is normally better practice to use multiple `Controllers`and 1 `Route`for each `Method` in your `Controller`. 
Do you use a Roles/Permission package? Or how are you roles stored?

Comment: I use roles / permission

Answer (score 0):

Step one, get a laravel package that is going to help you manage roles and permissions, I would recommend something like [spatie laravel permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction)

Step two would be to have a controller for reporting and assign it a route, when a user with a particular role, logs in, then just get redirected to that route.

For redirecting part you can use middleware for this purpose and then in controller constructor use it as in the example below.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

And then you need to secure routes where you want from user to be logged in to access.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
      Route::get('/yourReportPath', 'YourReportController@index');
});
```

Please do a little reading on middleware [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware)

Comment: Can you explain a little more?
How to redirect them to authorized pages

Comment: Updated my post with examples